# EMPTY_BLOB in OracleParameter ODP.NET

Tags: blob, nullable, odp.net

I use ODP.NET (not managed).
I have an update sqlstring for set BLOB and DateTime fields.

I want update BLOB field to **"EMPTY_BLOB"** too using ODP.NET, and the same parameter *:pDATOS*.

My sql string:

```
public const string SqlStringUpdate = "UPDATE " + SqlTableName + " SET "
    + "DATOS=:pDATOS, FECHAEMPAQUETADO=:pFECHAEMPAQUETADO "
    + "WHERE (ID_DESPLIEGUE = :pID_DESPLIEGUE OR :pID_DESPLIEGUE IS NULL)";
```

I use OracleParameter like this:

```
oracleParameter = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter();
oracleParameter.ParameterName = "pDATOS";
oracleParameter.OracleDbType = Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Blob;
oracleParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
myCommand.Add(oracleParameter);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new OracleBlob with nothing in it and bind that. It will be an empty blob.